# DataTable: In case of Date field in Db, show only date indead of datetime on UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, ado.net

I have one page created in the asp.net core(3.1) website. On the page, user have to specify database connection and then 'table name'(any table present in specified databse). The same page also contains the **preview** button.
On click of the 'Preview' button, I need to go to the database and fetch the first 100 rows and display in preview section of the page.

We are using ado.net to fetch the data and will a data table like

```
public static DataTable GetTableData(int displayCount, string tableName, string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT top(@DisplayCount)* FROM {0}", tableName);

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayCount", displayCount);

    SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    sqlAdapter.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
      {
        return ds.Tables[0];
      }
    }
return null;
}
```

In the model, I have property 'PreviewDataTable'.
Now on Page, I am showing data like this.

```
 <table class="table mb-0">
     <thead>
        <tr>
             @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.PreviewDataTable.Columns)
             {
                 <th scope="col">@col.ColumnName</th>
             }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (DataRow row in Model.PreviewDataTable.Rows)
            {
                <tr>
                   @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.PreviewDataTable.Columns)
                   {
                      <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                   }
               </tr>
            }
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

**PROBLEM:**
If I have a table with 2 columns one is of date and the other is of DateTime. like below

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EkrZ.png)

On preview section it shows like following.

[image]

In the preview section, the 'c_date' column also shows the time along with date although it is a date.
How can I show date only in case of a date field?

**Additional information:**

While debugging(if we try to use reflection), I get to know that for Date field (C_Date) the data type in DataTable is 'DateTime'. Please check the following image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 18/08/2020**

From the [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings?redirectedfrom=MSDN), we can see `Date` from `SQL` will transform to `DateTime` automatically. So you need to convert with new format or show in new format.

> Show **Date** without using **ColumnName**

[image]

Codes of showing the value

```
              <td>
                @{
                    DateTime dtDate;

                    if (DateTime.TryParse(@row[col.ColumnName].ToString(), out dtDate))
                    {
                        bool isTimeNull = (dtDate.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero);

                        if (isTimeNull)
                        {
                            @Convert.ToDateTime(row[col.ColumnName]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                        }
                        else
                            @row[col.ColumnName];
                    }
                    else
                        @row[col.ColumnName];
                }
            </td>
```

> How can I show date only in case of a date field?

**@Convert.ToDateTime(row[col.ColumnName]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");**

Screenshot of test:

[image]

**Codes of table in View:**

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (DataRow row in Model.PreviewDataTable.Rows)
        {
        <tr>
            @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.PreviewDataTable.Columns)
            {
            <td>
                @if (col.ColumnName.Equals("C_Date"))
                {
                    @Convert.ToDateTime(row[col.ColumnName]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                }
                else
                {
                    @row[col.ColumnName];
                }

            </td>
            }
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, if we have fixed columns then this answer is correct but in our case table name is input.
Therefore the column names are also not fixed, the user can pass any Tabe name and we need to fetch the data from Table and show on UI.
So we cannot put the check on Column name.

Comment: if so, we could check the time to decide which type to display.